# OpenMP low performance

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a loop in my program so i searched about multi-threading. First i took a look on POSIX multithreaded programming tutorial, it was so complicated so i tried to do something easier. I tried with OpenMP. I have successfully parallelized my code but the problem of execution time get worser than the serial case. this is below a portion ok my program. I wish you tell me what's the problem. Should i specify what variables are shared and what are private? and how can i know the kind of each variable? i wish you answer me because i searched in many forums and i still don't know what to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define D                0.215         // magnetic dipolar constant

main()
{
  int     i,j,n,p,NTOT = 1600,Nc = NTOT-1;
  float   r[2],spin[2*NTOT],w[2],d;
  double  E,F,V,G,dU;
  .
  .
  .
  for(n = 1; n <= Nc; n++){
    fscanf(voisins,"%d%d%f%f%f",&i,&j,&r[0],&r[1],&d);
    V = 0.0;E = 0.0;F = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
      #pragma omp for schedule(auto)
      for(p = 0;p < 2;p++)
      {
        V += (D/pow(d,3.0))*(spin[2*i-2+p]-w[p])*spin[2*j-2+p];
        E += (spin[2*i-2+p]-w[p])*r[p];
        F += spin[2*j-2+p]*r[p];
      }
    }
    G = -3*(D/pow(d,5.0))*E*F;
    dU += (V+G);
   }
   .
   .
   .
 }//End of main()
```

Comment: *the problem of execution time get worser than the serial case* This is often a result of using the wrong timing routine(s).  Your code doesn't show what you are using, best make sure it is `omp_get_wtime`.

Answer (score 2):

You are parallelizing a loop with only 2 iterations: `p=0` and `p=1`. The way that OpenMP's `omp for` works is by splitting up the loop iterations among your threads in the parallel team (which you've defined as 4 threads) and letting them work through their part of the problem in parallel.

With only 2 iterations, 2 of your threads will be sitting idle. On top of that, actually figuring out which threads will work on which part of the problem takes overhead. And if your actual loop doesn't take long (which in this case it clearly doesn't), the overhead will cost more than the benefits you've gained from parallelization.

A better strategy is usually to parallelize the outermost loops with OpenMP whenever possible in order to solve both the problems of splitting up the work evenly and reducing the (relative) overhead. Alternatively, you can parallelize at the lowest loop level using OpenMP 4.0's `omp simd` command.

Lastly, you are not computing the variables `V`, `E`, and `F` correctly. Because they are summed from iteration to iteration, you should define them all as reduction variables with `reduction(+:V)`. I would be surprised if you are currently getting the correct answer as is.

(Also as High Performance Mark says: make sure you're timing the wall time execution of your program and not the CPU time execution of your program. This is typically done with `omp_get_wtime()`.)

Comment: Thank you Nose for you answer i think it is helpfull. I tied to parallelize the outer loop but in this case the CPU's activity in top show that 45% is dedicated to us, 15% for sy and 40% for id which is not the case when i parallelize the inner loop (99% for us). I do understand what you said about the two idle threads but the problem of time persist. You think i shoud say which variables are shared and which are private to avoid race conditions?

Comment: The default for OpenMP is that every variable is shared. When parallelizing your inner loop in this case, you only need to specify that `V`, `E`, and `F` are reduction variables, and `p` is private.

Comment: Parallelizing your outer loop (which I believe is the way to go) will require `#pragma omp parallel for private(n, V, E, F, p, G) reduction(+:dU) num_threads(4)`

Comment: Also, FYI: you should see 4 threads running at near 100% (or sometimes you see this as 1 "thread" running at 400%) when you run `top` from your Linux command line. The fact that you are only seeing 45% means that you might not have set up your system correctly. What does it say when you run the single-threaded version of the code?

Comment: Sorry Nose i just was a little confused. I tried #pragma omp parallel for private(n, V, E, F, p, G) reduction(+:dU) num_threads(4) and the same problem persist. it's always like this CPU0 45%us CPU1 45%us  CPU2 45%us CPU3 45%us... but when i put num_threads(1) it's CPU3 100%us, 0%id and the rest 0%us, 99%id just like in the serial case.

Comment: Hi Nose. I tried to put # pragma omp critical after the first loop and i got a significant boost in performance. all CPU's are 100% ;) but it still slower than the serial case